# WITH statement not working when calling another sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and it doesn't work.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheet")
Call fill_number_axsr(wks, .Cells(cell.Row, col).Value)
```

In the Watches window, I got:

```
.Cells(cell.Row, col).Value : <Expression not defined in context>
```

If I added the qualifier, I got the correct result:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheet").Cells(cell.Row, col).Value : 1000000
```

Does this mean the WITH statement doesn't work when calling a sub or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The value passed is 0, instead of 1000000.

Comment: I'm not sure you've given us enough detail to be able to reproduce this. What does `Debug.Print .Cells(cell.Row, col).Value` return?

Comment: Are you talking about Immediate Window? I got "compiler error: invalid or unqualified reference".

Comment: Put that line inside the `With` block.

Comment: You mean the code? It IS inside a WITH block. I just didn't show the remaining code. Actually, there are only two more lines, one to call another SUB, the other END WITH.

Comment: Put the `Debug.Print .Cells(cell.Row, col).Value` inside the `With` block - otherwise it is an unqualified reference and you get that compile error.

Comment: How do I do that? I hardly use Debug.Print. I mostly rely on the Watches window.

Comment: Literally put that exact line inside the `With` block, add a breakpoint if needed and rerun. Great time to learn `Debug.Print`!

Comment: OK. Let me study how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Another key thing to explain is what are the following variables, and what *should* they be: `cell.Row`, `col`, `wks`. I've created a quick example based on your question and had no problems passing a cell value within a `With` block to a public function. I would assume you are working this out based on your discussion prior about using `Debug.Print`. Please update your question with some more info :)